# add font awesome icon to w3 col

Tags: html, icons

I added w3 col to separate some address. Now I want to add icon in front of addresses and phone and etc. But It is unable. What is the wrong in that code friends?

```html
<p style="font-size:24px;">Keep In Touch With Us</p>
<div class="w3-row">
  <div class="w3-col w3-container" style="width:19%; margin-left:2%;">
  <p> 
 <ul class="demo"> 
 <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pink Maid Beauty Salon (Main Centre), <br>No. 789, <br>High Level Road, <br> Colombo 02</li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> 011-2298024 <br>077-3053912</li>
  <li>pinkmaidbeautysalon@gmail.com</li>
  <li>8.00 A.M - 6.00 P.M</li>
   
</ul></div>

  <div class="w3-col w3-container" style="width:19%">
  <p><ul class="demo"> 
  <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pink Maid Beauty Salon (Branch), <br>No.261/1, <br> Sri Dewamiththa Rd, <br>China Garden,Galle</li>
  <li>091-2212345 <br> 071-4229276</li>
 <li>pinkmaidbeautysalon@gmail.com</li>
  <li>8.00 A.M - 6.00 P.M</li>
    
</ul></div>
```

Comment: Please add Font awesome css library link.

Comment: @xxCodexx It is working. Thank You So much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the code with font awesome url. And it seems to be working. Please check.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p style="font-size:24px;">Keep In Touch With Us</p>
<div class="w3-row">
  <div class="w3-col w3-container" style="width:19%; margin-left:2%;">
  <p> 
 <ul class="demo"> 
 <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pink Maid Beauty Salon (Main Centre), <br>No. 789, <br>High Level Road, <br> Colombo 02</li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> 011-2298024 <br>077-3053912</li>
  <li>pinkmaidbeautysalon@gmail.com</li>
  <li>8.00 A.M - 6.00 P.M</li>
   
</ul></div>

  <div class="w3-col w3-container" style="width:19%">
  <p><ul class="demo"> 
  <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pink Maid Beauty Salon (Branch), <br>No.261/1, <br> Sri Dewamiththa Rd, <br>China Garden,Galle</li>
  <li>091-2212345 <br> 071-4229276</li>
 <li>pinkmaidbeautysalon@gmail.com</li>
  <li>8.00 A.M - 6.00 P.M</li>
    
</ul></div>
```